# Where statement in a Linq request

Tags: c#, linq

I try to execute this Linq request :

```
var lqClassResult = from classItem in this.dataSet._class.AsEnumerable()
    join namespaceItem in this.dataSet._namespace.AsEnumerable()
    on classItem.Field<int>("namespace_id") equals namespaceItem.Field<int>("id")
    where classItem.Field<string>("class_name").ToLowerInvariant().Contains(className.ToLowerInvariant()) &&
          namespaceItem.Field<string("namespace_name").ToLowerInvariant().Contains(namespaceName.ToLowerInvariant())                                   
    orderby namespaceItem.Field<string>("namespace_name"),classItem.Field<string>("class_name")
    select new { 
         class_name = classItem.Field<string>("class_name"), 
         namespace_name = namespaceItem.Field<string>("namespace_name") 
    };
```

But when i execute it, Visual Studio Throw a NullReferenceException because of this line :

    `namespaceItem.Field("namespace_name").ToLowerInvariant().Contains(namespaceName.ToLowerInvariant())`

 in where clause.

If anyone can help me it would be great

Comment: You can null coalesce (`a??b` means `a` unless `a` is null and then `b`) with the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
on classItem.Field<int>("namespace_id") equals namespaceItem.Field<int>("id")  
let namespaceName = namespaceItem.Field<string("namespace_name")
where classItem.Field<string>("class_name").ToLowerInvariant().Contains(className.ToLowerInvariant()) && namespace != null && 
      namespace.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(namespaceName.ToLowerInvariant())
```

Answer (score 0):

I would *guess* that `namespaceItem.Field("namespace_name")` is returning null.

Is this a valid return value for that method? If not, then check your underlying code.

If this *is* a valid return value then you need to check for a null before calling ToLowerInvariant():

```
var lqClassResult = from classItem in this.dataSet._class.AsEnumerable()
    join namespaceItem in this.dataSet._namespace.AsEnumerable()
    on classItem.Field<int>("namespace_id") equals namespaceItem.Field<int>("id")
    where classItem.Field<string>("class_name").ToLowerInvariant().Contains(className.ToLowerInvariant()) &&
          namespaceItem.Field<string("namespace_name") ! =  null &&
          namespaceItem.Field<string("namespace_name").ToLowerInvariant().Contains(namespaceName.ToLowerInvariant())                                   
    orderby namespaceItem.Field<string>("namespace_name"),classItem.Field<string>("class_name")
    select new { 
         class_name = classItem.Field<string>("class_name"), 
         namespace_name = namespaceItem.Field<string>("namespace_name") 
    };
```

Note the extra null check:

```
      namespaceItem.Field<string("namespace_name") ! =  null &&
```

However, this is only a guess: you need to determine where the null value is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

2 possibilities:

- There is no field

> Field("namespace_name")

returns null because there is no field-

- There isa field, but

Field("namespace_name").ToLowerInvariant().

returns null because the VALUE in namespace_name is a null so ToLowerInvariant also returns null, which will blow the contains.